# Conversion of the outputs of a for loop into an array

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am learning Python and coding in general and here's something I stumbled upon:

```
n=int(input())
for i in range(1,n+1):
       print(i)
```

Now, I want the output in the form of an array. So if `n=4`, I want the output to look like `my_array = [1,2,3,4]`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The range function return an iterator that you can also directly convert in to array with the python cast

```py
n=int(input())
my_array = list(range(1,n+1))
```

**Explanation:**
In python 2.7, range() directly returns a list whereas in python 3.x range() is a generator so that is the reason we need to convert it t the list.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing a individual elements using `for` loop. If you want `list` as output then you can do:

```
n = int(input())

# use list comprehension
# my_array = [i+1 for i in range(n)]

# or you can do it:
my_array = list(range(1,n+1))

print(my_array)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Your solution has one unnecessary loop. The better solution would be: my_array = list(range(1, n+1))

Answer (score 0):

**Try to List comprehension:**

```
n =int(input('Enter the number'))
my_list = [i for i in range(1,n+1)]
```